# How to use pre-trained BERT question-answering model for text extraction in Python?

Tags: csv, text-extraction, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, nlp-question-answering

So, let's say I have a following csv dataset. I have to use pre-trained BERT question-answering model to train , predict and finally evaluate. As, I am new to this it would be helpful to see similar project to understand and work myself on my project or any guidance would be helpful too.

I already tried training the model individually (checking one article at a time), that works. I need guidance on how to work with CSV dataset and evaluation.

[Here is the format of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAGU1.png)

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: What have you tried so far, with a code example? / What do you expect? / What error do you get? For help, take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: I have trained and checked the pre-trained question answering BERT model with single article, how do I go about if I have a CSV and one column has many articles and I want to use them for training? Any similar projects (I couldn't find any myself) would help me to understand all the steps involved in the process.

Comment: Which model are you using? It is important to know if the model is just pre-trained of it has been fine-tuned for question answering as well. If it's the latter, you could maybe avoid another fine-tuning. Please provide details about the model and I might be able to help you more